# Python Script to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to use python script to update my database. When I try run the script, the output says `text:` or other data types, before the actual value of the field. Any tips on how to get rid of this?

```
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    EasementNumber = (unicode(sheet.cell(r, 0)))
    Grantor = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r, 1)))
    Book = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,2)))
    Page = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,3)))
    Day = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,4)))
    Month = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,5)))
    Year = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,6)))
    EasementType = str(sheet.cell(r,7))
    Origin = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,8)))
    Descriptions = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,9)))
    ProjectName = str(unicode(sheet.cell(r,10)))

    values = (EasementNumber, Grantor, Book, Page, Day, Month, Year, EasementType, Origin, Descriptions, ProjectName)

    cursor.execute(query, values)

cursor.close()

cursor.commit()
```

Comment: without the code, nobody can say, why you see `text:`

Comment: Added the code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting cell-objects to strings, instead of using the `value` of the `cell`.

Instead of reading the cells one by one, you can get all values of a row at once:

```
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    values = sheet.row_values(row, 0, 11)
    cursor.execute(query, values)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot!